# Start AVD always with the same settings

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

What I would like to do:

- create manually AVD
- change device settings
- save it somehow
- always start AVD with the same settings as set right after creation

Is there any simple way to save state of AVD and load it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Manually create your AVD
2. Change it's settings - for example turn on security
3. Locate AVD on your hard drive
4. Copy userdata-qemu.img to other location -> it contains of your current emulator configuration
5. Start emulator by terminal by

> emulator -avd AVD_NAME -initdata PATH/userdata-qemu.img -wipe-data

- wipe-data resets whole AVD to state after creation
- initdata sets file under path as initial state

By doing so your emulator will always launch with the same state as saved in userdata-qemu.img.